# Sort list of tuples "fairly"

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of tuples that I need to be sorted "fairly".  Each tuple contains two values, the first value represents the height and the second the age.  I'm trying to work out the best way to sort this list that would factor in both values so it should be sorted from shortest to tallest AND oldest to youngest, but have more weighting on height than age.  For example, if I had the following list:

```
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+
| index       | 0   | 1   | 2   | 3  | 4   | 5   |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+
| Age (days)  | 103 | 110 | 69  | 83 | 110 | 109 |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+
| Height (mm) | 0   | 1   | 4   | 5  | 5   | 39  |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

I would expect it to sorted to something like this:

```
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+
| Age (days)  | 103 | 110 | 110 | 83 | 69  | 109 |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+
| Height (mm) | 0   | 1   | 5   | 5  | 4   | 39  |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

You can find a real life example here: https://repl.it/join/lalawflp-aqrab

This project is written in Python, so any code examples in python will be helpful.

Comment: What you're describing is standard behaviour for sorting tuples in Python. Have you even tried anything yourself? Just `sorted(mylist_of_tuples)` works. Also, don't share links to sites (especially ones that require logins) that have the code, instead just share the parts of code you think are relevant here - it's OK to include a link to a repository or repl for extra detail.

Comment: @Grismar Their output example isn't using the standard behaviour.

Comment: Ah thank @superbrain - you are correct, thanks; doesn't change the fact the question lacks any effort making it clear what was tried of course.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried  custom weighting for  your array elements using `sorted` function

```
sorted(items, key = lambda x: x[0] * age_weight + x[1] * height_weight)
```

I'm not sure if you have predefined values for the weights of height/age, but you can keep tuning them till you are satisfied with the results.

Comment: Given it's oldest to youngest, the `age_weight` should probably be negative. Otherwise, yeah, this is basically the only "answer"; they have to define the weights, because sorting on both height and age *at once* (rather than using one as a fallback for ties in the other) is decidedly non-standard, and there is no objective way to weight them.

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic solution is:

```
list_of_tupples = [(103, 0), (110, 1), (69, 4), (83, 5), (110, 5), (109, 39)]
print(sorted(list_of_tupples, key=lambda x: (x[0]*1 + x[1]*20)))
```

Playing around with the weights in the lambda function, I was able to get this output:

```
[(103, 0), (110, 1), (69, 4), (83, 5), (110, 5), (109, 39)]
```

You may need to map these to a multivariable polynomial to get the output you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

this worked with me, you can come with better than O(n^2)
first i sorted the tuples in the list wrt first element in the tuple

```py
for i in range(length):
    for x in range(length):
        if(lst[i][0]<lst[x][0]):
           lst[i],lst[x]=lst[x],lst[i]
```

then we have now sorted list of tuples wrt to the first element in the tuples and now we want to sort the wrt the second element

we just do the same but if the first element in the tuple of i and x equals we check if the two tuples

```js
for i in range(length):
    for x in range(length):
        if(lst[i][0]==lst[x][0]):
            if(lst[i][1]<lst[x][1]):
                 lst[i],lst[x]=lst[x],lst[i]
```

then you can print the list or use it